# Iterator returns garbage

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Cannot figure out where I went wrong.  As I understand, this code should return "1, 2, 3" but I get the following.  I need the vector and its iterators declared globally because I am passing the vector to functions in my actual code and need to update the iterators as well in some functions.  Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<float> grid;
vector<float>::iterator gridPtr;

int main()

{
  grid.push_back(1);
  grid.push_back(2);

  gridPtr = grid.begin();

  grid.push_back(3);

  cout << "gridPtr: " << *gridPtr << endl;

  gridPtr++;

  cout << "gridPtr: " << *gridPtr << endl;

  gridPtr++;

  cout << "gridPtr: " << *gridPtr << endl;
}
```

This returns:

```
gridPtr: 2.62257e-33
gridPtr: 2
gridPtr: 0
```

Comment: *"because I am passing the vector to functions in my actual code"* - If you are passing it to the functions, then why does it need to be global? That seems contradictory.

Comment: JBentley - My mistake, I meant I am using them in a function and don't want to have to pass them.

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6438087/1227469) for an explanation of iterator invalidation.

Comment: @David The OOP way would be to make the vector a private member of a class, with public member functions which operate on it.

Answer (score 4):

`push_back()` may invalidate all iterators. Namely, if it has to reallocate the backing store, all existing iterators become invalidated.

If you know ahead of time how many elements you're going to push, you can use `reserve()` to preallocate the necessary memory, which will prevent `push_back()` from reallocating (and thus invalidating iterators).

Answer (score 2):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back:

> If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()`, all **iterators and references are invalidated.**

(Emphasis mine.)

This makes sense when you consider what's happening under the hood; a `vector` works by filling up a dynamically-allocated array; when it's full it needs to reallocate a bigger one, and move everything across.

Answer (score 1):

You may invalidate the `iterator` when you do a `push_back`, if you remove that line it should work fine. The following will work as expected:

```
grid.push_back(1);
grid.push_back(2);

gridPtr = grid.begin();
cout << "gridPtr: " << *gridPtr << endl;
gridPtr++;
cout << "gridPtr: " << *gridPtr << endl;
```

as Kevin mentioned, using `reserve` to allocate enough memory before-hand will also fix the issue:

```
grid.reserve(3) ;
grid.push_back(1);
grid.push_back(2);

gridPtr = grid.begin();

grid.push_back(3) ;
cout << "gridPtr: " << *gridPtr << endl;
gridPtr++;
cout << "gridPtr: " << *gridPtr << endl;
gridPtr++;
cout << "gridPtr: " << *gridPtr << endl;
```